# Creating view from multiple list in Sharepoint 2013 out of box?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view

I have created 3 list. In 1st list, there are 2 fields. In 2nd list, there are 3 fields. In 3rd list, there are 2 fields. I am in need to create view  using those 3 lists by viewing some fields only. how to do it in SharePoint 2013 out of box? Kindly guide me....

Answer (score 4):

A view is created per list. However, if you want to show data from three lists you can use Content Query webpart. See these link for more information about CQWP.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-designer-help/display-data-from-multiple-lists-with-the-content-query-web-part-HA010174134.aspx

http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2011/09/sharepoint-2010-content-query-webpart.html

Comment: The top link no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharePoint Designer to create a DataView, Firstly you need to create a Linked Data Source where you can choose more than one List and create a Linked data source you can either merge or join the Lists. After creating the linked data source create a dataview using the linked data source and your view will be ready with more than one lists.

Comment: like how can i implement this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a linked list view by going into SharePoint Designer. Here is a link on how to do this: http://ignatiuz.com/blog/how-to-link-two-lists-and-create-a-combined-view-in-sharepoint-2013/

**Edit: New active link as of Sept 2019:** https://www.ignatiuz.com/blog/sharepoint-2013/how-to-link-two-lists-and-create-a-combined-view-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: 404 Not Found on link